# Listing files,subfolders and their files in a file in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, directory

my Uploads folder structure in codeigniter is like
Uploads
-File1.txt
-File2.txt
-Subfolder 1
 -- File1.txt
 --File2.txt
-Subfilder2
 --File1.txt

I want to display each file name and if that file is in subfilder it should display as Subfilder/File.txt

Thats what my code looks like

```
" <?php 
                    foreach ($direcotry as $key => $value ) {

                        if(!is_numeric($key)){
                            echo $key . '/' ;
                           foreach ($key as $subKey => $value) {
                               echo $value . '<br>';
                           }
                        }
                        else{ 
                            echo $value . '</br>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>"
```

![enter image description here][1]
and it gives an error as invalid argument to foreach

Comment: you need to upload the image somewhere else cuz of your low reputation.

Answer (score 0):

CodeIgniter contains directory helper which provides this for you

```
$this->load->helper('directory');
$map = directory_map('path/to/uploads');
print_r($map)
```